# How to access ToggleButton content in a storyboard animation

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, animation, binding, storyboard

I have a toggle button in UI and would like to perform some action when it is clicked.

xaml for this button:

```
      <ToggleButton x:Name="markToggle" Click="markToggle_Click" Style="{StaticResource StyleMarkToggle}" >
         <ToggleButton.Content>
           <StackPanel x:Name="markToggle_Button" Orientation="Horizontal">
             <Image x:Name="Icon" Source="{Binding MarkToggleIcon}" Stretch="None" />
             <TextBlock x:Name="Counter" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ButtonText}" Margin="6,0,0,0" />
           </StackPanel>
         </ToggleButton.Content>
      </ToggleButton>
```

When this toggleButton is clicked, I want to change the Foreground color of textblock (name: Counter). 
How do I access this textbox element from Storyboard.Target (or TargetName)?

Here is the xaml code for 'StyleMarkToggle' style.

(Only visual state 'checked' is shown in the below code.)

```
<VisualState x:Name="Checked">
 <Storyboard>
      <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="White" Storyboard.TargetName="{Binding ElementName=Counter}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />
 </Storyboard>
```

It shows this runtime error:

```
MS.Internal.WrappedException: Cannot resolve TargetName System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve TargetName System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.VisualStateManager_GoToStateInternal(Control reference, FrameworkElement root, VisualStateGroup group, VisualState state, Boolean useTransitions, Boolean& refreshInheritanceContext)
   at System.Windows.VisualStateManager.RetryGoToStateAfterRefreshingInheritanceContext(Control control, FrameworkElement templateRoot, VisualStateGroup group, VisualState state, Boolean useTransitions)
   at System.Windows.VisualStateManager.GoToState(Control control, String stateName, Boolean useTransitions)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.ChangeVisualState(Boolean useTransitions)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.OnApplyTemplate()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnApplyTemplate(IntPtr nativeTarget)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `Storyboard`, you could just bind the `Foreground` property of the `TextBlock` element to the `IsChecked` property of the `ToggleButton` element and use a `Converter` to convert from `bool` to `SolidColorBrush`.

Here is the modified XAML:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="markToggle" Click="markToggle_Click" Style="{StaticResource StyleMarkToggle}" >
    <ToggleButton.Content>
        <StackPanel x:Name="markToggle_Button" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image x:Name="Icon" Source="{Binding MarkToggleIcon}" Stretch="None" />
            <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding ElementName=markToggle, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}" x:Name="Counter" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ButtonText}" Margin="6,0,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ToggleButton.Content>
</ToggleButton>
```

And the code for the converter:

```
public class BoolToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)value)
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        else
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: Yes I can, but since I was using storyboard for other purpose, I thought it would make more sense to update Foreground color of textblock using storyboard.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible in pure XAML. It can't resolve "Counter" because that TextBlock is local to the ToggleButton.Content